# EasyMock - Partial Mocking assigning the mock to specific field

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, easymock

In EasyMock, when using annotation @Mock
You can set the to which member of the target object the mock will be assigned, using fieldName
Example:

```
/*assign mock impl ONLY for myInterface2 member of tested object*/
@Mock(type= MockType.NICE, name="secondMember", fieldName = "myInterface2")
private MyInterfaceImpl myInterfaceMock; //step 1 for runner
```

This is very convenient as I don't need to create a special constructor to assign the internal members with mocked objects

Question:
Is there such thing for partial mocking as well?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. `@Mock` can't create partial mocks (yet). You can request it as a feature request: https://github.com/easymock/easymock/issues

Comment: thanks man
however I was asking something else: can I state the target field in the target object that mock will be injected to, when doing partial mock
similar to how its done when using annotations
thanks

Comment: If I understood correctly this time, it is not possible with EasyMock. But it is classical field setting using reflection. For easiness, you could use `ReflectionTestUtils` from Spring test framework for instance.